# Why does constructing elements of list comprehensions in place produce a different result from constructing in a constraint?

Tags: haskell, list-comprehension

Why do these two comprehensions produce different lists?

```
l1 = [[x,-x] | x <- [1..]]

l2 = [pxnx | x <- [1..], pxnx <- [x,-x]]
```

Aren't these two statements the same? The results look like this:

```
Prelude> take 10 l1
[[1,-1],[2,-2],[3,-3],[4,-4],[5,-5],[6,-6],[7,-7],[8,-8],[9,-9],[10,-10]]

Prelude> take 10 l2
[1,-1,2,-2,3,-3,4,-4,5,-5]
```

Comment: "Aren't these two statements the same?" Obviously they are not.

Comment: And obviously that was a rhetorical question meaning "why are they not the same"...

Comment: A rhetorical question? What is this, literarycriticism.stackexchange.com? Anyway the answer is pretty straightforward if you replace `[x,-x]` with a non-list. Try `(-x, x)`. The first list happily computes away and the second one becomes an error.

Comment: Why would they be the same? `<-` does not assign the list `[x, -x]` to `pxnx`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your definitions can be written equivalently, as others have noted, as

```
l1 = [[x,-x] | x <- [1..]]
   = [pxnx | x <- [1..], let pxnx = [x,-x]  ]
   = [pxnx | x <- [1..], pxnx <-   [[x,-x]] ]      -- NB

l2 = [pxnx | x <- [1..], pxnx <-    [x,-x]  ]
```

As can readily be seen, these are *not* equivalent expressions.

The question boils down to the meaning of `<-` in list comprehensions.

More generally, this can be written in pseudocode as

```
l1 = for each x in [1..]:
        yield [x,-x]

   = for each x in [1..]:
        for each pxnx in [[x,-x]]:    -- NB: only _one_ element in this list
            yield pxnx

l2 = for each x in [1..]:
        for each pxnx in  [x,-x] :    -- NB: _two_ elements in this list
            yield pxnx
```

Though the two `for` loops are *nested*, the `yield` is "the same": it specifies the next element in the list being constructed.

So you see, you do *not* "construct it in the constraint". This is a *nested generator*.

Answer (score 3):

```
l1 = [[x,-x] | x <- [1..]]

l2 = [pxnx | x <- [1..], pxnx <- [x,-x]]
```

These list comprehensions are equivalent to operations in the list monad. In `do` notation they would be:

```
l1 = do
  x <- [1..]
  return [x,-x]

l2 = do
  x <- [1..]
  pxnx <- [x,-x]
  return pxnx
```

These, in turn, desugar into calls to bind (`>>=`) and `return`:

```
l1 = [1..] >>= \x -> return [x,-x]

l2 = [1..] >>= \x -> [x,-x] >>= \pxnx -> return pxnx
```

Finally, we can inline the definitions of `>>=` and `return` for lists:

```
l1 = concatMap (\x -> [[x,-x]]) [1..]

l2 = concatMap (\x -> concatMap (\pxnx -> [pxnx]) [x,-x]) [1..]
```

And simplify:

```
l1 = map (\x -> [x,-x]) [1..]

l2 = concatMap (\x -> [x,-x]) [1..]
```

So `l2` is exactly the same as `concat l1`. Note that `<-` implies “execute this action”, which for the list monad means “iterate over each element of the list”. If you wanted something resembling `l2` but with the same result as `l1`, you might use `let` instead of `<-`:

```
l2 = [pxnx | x <- [1..], let pxnx = [x,-x]]
```

This is just as if you had written the following in `do` notation:

```
l2 = do
  x <- [1..]
  let pxnx = [x,-x]
  return pxnx
```

Comment: "sugar" is a bit too strong a claim;  [haskell2010 report](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-420003.11) says: "List comprehensions satisfy these identities, which may be used as a translation into the kernel" and then gives a set of re-write rules based in `concatMap` directly. `MonadComprehensions` probably do translate into `do` code. (Just a side note.)

Comment: @WillNess: Fair enough, made the wording a bit more bitter. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Let's take a look at both of those expressions.

In the first one we can see that on the left side of the list comprehension we have a list of two elements `x` and `-x`, so we know that the list we get from the list comprehension must be at least a depth 2 list `[[a]]` for some type `a` (probably bound by some number typeclass).

On the right side of the list comprehension we are taking the positive integers `1..` and storing them, one by one, into `x`.

So this expression should give us a list of lists of the positive intergers paired with their negative counterparts.

```
[[x,-x] | x <- [1..]]
```

In the second one we can see that the left side just contains a variable, so all we can determine from that alone is that the list must be of at least depth 1.

If we look at the right side we can see that like in the previous expression it is storing the positive integers into `x`. However, unlike the previous expression it is placing the + - integer pairs one by one into `pxnx`.

This results in this expression yielding a list of type `[a]`, as opposed to the previous expression's type of `[[a]]`.

Additionally, this list contains all of the positive numbers and their negative counterparts, like the previous list, however it instead stores them all in the same list, rather than storing each pair in a separate list.

```
[pxnx | x <- [1..], pxnx <- [x,-x]]
```

This difference is due to the fact that in `pxnx <- [x,-x]`, the values `x` and `-x` are stored, **one by one**, into pxnx. Whereas in the first expression they are stored as a combined list.

Comment: What do you mean by "one by one"? That seems to be the key difference.

Comment: By "one by one" I mean that each element in a list is mapped to a single element in the output or intermediate list. This is what the `<-` operator does. For example, say we just had `[x | x <- [1, -1]]` this would yield a list where the elements in `[1, -1]` are each separate elements in the resulting list.

Comment: Ah! Okay now I see. I had a wrong idea of what `<-` does.

Answer (score 1):

They produce a different result because `<-` is not `=`.

These are the same:

```
l1 = [[x,-x] | x <- [1..]]

l2 = [pxnx | x <- [1..], let pxnx = [x,-x]]
```

But `pxnx <- [x, -x]` loosely means `for pxnx in [x, -x]`, so in your case, we get one of each of `x` and `-x`.